# Can I create a class with f2py?

Tags: python, class, fortran, f2py

I want to use `f2py` to produce an object that behaves like a python class: it should store a piece of data such that the data need only be passed once. I would ultimately like to have python code like below, where `myfortranmodule` is a module compiled with `f2py`.

```python
from myfortranmodule import Analyzer

analyzer = Analyzer(bigvector)
for parameter in [0.0, 8.3, 10.2, ...]:
    answer = analyzer.get_answer(parameter)
```

Specifically, I need to structure it in this manner because `bigvector` is a very large piece of data and should only be passed once, the list of parameters in the for loop is long (and can't be passed ahead of time, as it is generated on-the-fly in python), and the `get_answer` method is computationally intensive, so should be done in fortran.

Is it possible to build such a class-like object with `f2py`, or otherwise store data in the fortran subroutine?

Comment: "it should store a piece of data in the method" Methods do not store data, they take in data and return data.

Comment: Edited the question to avoid suggesting the object is a method -- but the basic question remains.

Comment: *store data in the fortran subroutine*  What do you mean by that fragment ?  Fortran routines can be written such that internal variables 'remember' their values between invocations (learn about `save`).  More explanation is required.

Comment: @highperformancemark, the essential requirements are explained in the paragraph below the code: I only want to pass `bigvector` once, because it is a massive amount of data and will keep the same value, despite changing `parameter`. Then I'd call `get_answer` with many different values of `parameter`. Thanks for the tip on `save`; I'm trying to figure out if I can get that to work with `f2py`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to confirm that using a common block will do what you need. I actually stumbled across this from the opposite point of view; I was getting data persistence when I wanted a clean method call!
Since the Fortran routine was a long one I got round the problem by starting a `multiprocessing.process` calling the Fortran module from there and then `join` ing each time I wanted to run it. It was a simpler job than rewriting the Fortran to remove the common block.

```
q = mp.Queue()
cargs = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
p = mp.Process(target=module, args=(q, cargs))
p.start()
p.join()
result = q.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an imperfect answer to my question, since I now have a reasonable solution for my purposes. The workaround I have found is to use a "common block" in f2py, which allows direct access to designated variables in the fortran subroutine from python. (Note that this does not give *true* class-like behavior, as I cannot instantiate multiple classes that exist simultaneously with unique data values -- but it works for my purposes of passing the largest amount of data only once.)

A short example follows. Below is the example fortran code.

```
C file: common.f

      subroutine add(input, output)
          integer input,output,saved
          COMMON /DATA/ saved
cf2py     intent(in) :: input
cf2py     intent(out) :: output
          output = saved + input
      end

C end of common.f
```

This is compiled with

```
f2py -c -m common common.f
```

Then in python I can directly access and modify the value in `common.data.saved`, and when I call the subroutine `common.add` it returns the sum of the passed and stored values. Thus, the "stored" value(s) only need to be passed once, as requested in the original post.

```
>>> import common
>>> common.data.saved = 10
>>> common.add(1)
11
>>> common.add(100)
110
```

This is described in more detail in the [f2py Users Guide and Reference Manual](https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/#common-blocks).